# Form parameters are correct, but SQL misses a value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, insert

I have a form, that looks like this (sorry for Haml and the german parts)

```
  = form_for @mentality, :url => { :controller => "mentalities", :action => "create" }, :html => { :class => "mentality_create", :method => :post } do |f|
    = render 'shared/error_messages_einstellung', :object => f.object
      .left
        %h4
          Welche Einstellung möchten Sie hinzufügen?
        = f.text_field :title, :placeholder => "Name der Einstellung"
        %br
        = f.submit "Eintragen"
```

And a model which looks like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8 
class Mentality < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title

  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id,     :presence => true
  validates :title,       :presence => true

  default_scope :order => 'mentalities.created_at DESC'

  self.per_page = 20

end
```

So, there is only one field, which I want to write in, which is named title. If I process the create action, the log says:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ULjT8cxQ77KTh7+0rX6pzFpMaehBuUxGAA3AGh/Sbg8=", "mentality"=>{"title"=>"Test"}, "commit"=>"Eintragen"}
```

But the SQL Statement it creates, is missing the title:

```
INSERT INTO "mentalities" ("created_at", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ('2011-11-13 11:26:48.078652', NULL, '2011-11-13 11:26:48.078652', 1)
```

I have controller and views for a simliar model, which is named 'categories' and works perfectly fine.

So, can someybody explain why title isn't inserted into my database? I really don't understand why it's not there.

Comment: Fixed it.

I just removed the whole MVC and added it again. Still don't know why it happened but now it works.

Comment: Sometimes that's all that matters :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what it was, but I just removed the whole MVC and added it again. Still looks the same, but now it works.